# Angular.js: prevent view loading when browser loads for the first time?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

How can I prevent route loading when I hit refresh or when I load the page for the first time?

My backend respond with a chunk of HTML when ajax request and the whole page when normal request. If a normal request was made, I don't want angular to made the same request all over again to retrieve the same page but with a chunk of html instead of the whole page when the page loads.

How can I configure this?

Comment: Please provide a simple example illustrating your problem.

Comment: I have a website. When the request is ajax, it respond with the html section. When is a normal request it respond with the full website. When I first load the website, It already contains the html section that I need, but angular goes and fetch it anyway. What I need is to prevent the router fetching a template when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can't do that.

If you don't want the page to blink when angular load the whole page again, you can use the `resolve` attribute in angular-route or angular-ui-router.

You know, if angular don't load the page again, it can't handle user click or something else.

I have wrote a blog about this, researching the same problem with you, but in chinese. In the last, I decide to use `resolve`.

My blog url is http://isay.me/2014/06/angular-prerender-seo-and-use-resolve-for-page-flicker.html

Maybe you can have a look or not :)